If the number of intersection of two conics is an odd number, the quadratic forms are not simultaneous diagonalizable
I'm trying to do Exercise 3.6 at the end of this pdf (in $\Bbb CP^2$):


Show that the two quadratic forms
$$x^2+y^2-z^2, \quad x^2+y^2-y z$$
cannot be simultaneously diagonalized.


Attempt 1:
Their matrices don't commute:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{array}\right) \cdot\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0\end{array}\right)\ne\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0\end{array}\right) \cdot\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{array}\right)$$
but simultaneously diagonalizable matrices commute, so they cannot be simultaneously diagonalized.
Then I realize I am wrong. To diagonalize quadratic forms we want $S^TAS$ and $S^TBS$ to be diagonal matrices, but in the linked is another question: $S^{-1}AS$ and $S^{-1}BS$ are diagonal matrices.
Attempt 2:
I try to relate this exercise to a proposition in the PDF:

The non-diagonalizable case is where the intersection is at an odd number of points:


The two conics
$$x^2+y^2-z^2=0, \quad x^2+y^2-y z=0$$
intersect at two points $[1,\pm i,0]$ with multiplicity $1$, and one point $[0,1,1]$ with multiplicity $2$. So the intersection is at an odd number of points, so they cannot be simultaneously diagonalized.
But how do we prove this proposition?
Attempt 3:
For the first quadratic form $x^2+y^2-z^2$, let $z'=iz$, then $x^2+y^2-z^2=x^2+y^2+z'^2$, then the second quadratic form $x^2+y^2-yz=x^2+y^2+iyz'$, so it has matrix $\left(\begin{array}{lll}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{i}{2} \\ 0 & \frac{i}{2} & 0\end{array}\right)$.
The Jordan normal form of $\left(\begin{array}{lll}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{i}{2} \\ 0 & \frac{i}{2} & 0\end{array}\right)$ is $J=\left(\begin{array}{lll}\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$
WA computation
this is non-diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$, since it has a Jordan block of size $2$.
Is it true in general that, if $J$ is a $3\times3$ matrix with a Jordan block of size $>1$, and $I_3$ is the identity matrix, then the two corresponding conics has odd number of intersections?

Be careful. Diagonalizing quadratic forms is different from diagonalizing linear maps.

Given your symmetric matrices $A,B$  which are both invertible. Define $C= A^{-1} B.$   A necessary and sufficient condition to be able to construct $P$   such that both $P^T AP$ and $P^T BP$   are diagonal  is that $C$ be diagonalizable, that is $R^{-1}CR$  is diagonal.  Horn and Johnson 1985, paperback edition, page 229 has nice table of results. The construction for case II  is pages 231-232. That title is Matrix Analysis. Their 1991 book is Topics in Matrix Analysis.

Look at that, your $A^{-1} B$  is not diagonalizable.
